# CSS3 Keyframes not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

Below is the code -

```
.startanimation {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-animation: animate 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
    100% {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
    }
}
```

In the HTML when an element is given a class "startanimation", the animation works. But when the same class is added to another element using "addClass" method, the anmition does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle

Comment: @Vangel Tzo - http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/8477/

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/d3md7597/1/

```js
$('#start').on('click', function() {
  $('#x').addClass('startanimation')
})
$('#stop').on('click', function() {
  $('#x').removeClass('startanimation')
})
```

```css
#x {
  background: pink;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 200px;
}
.startanimation {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-animation: animate 1s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  100% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="x"></div>
```